# FlashForge Finder turns off mid print and is unable to reset or update firmware

Tags: print-failure, flashforge-finder

I am new to 3D printing and am trying to get started with a FlashForge Finder. Unfortunately, the printer keeps shutting off mid print, and I am unable to find a cause. Here's what I have tried thus far:

- **System Settings**

  - **Factory Reset** - When I attempt a factory reset, nothing happens (the menu closes, but usage stats & wifi do not get reset)
  - **Firmware Update** - Updating the firmware from the touchscreen immediately fails every time
- **Printing**

  - I can start a new print, but the machine turns off after about ~10-15 minutes at temperature
  - The transformer on the power cable remains lit green even after the machine fails and turns off
  - I have tried printing multiple files from Thingiverse with no edits (an elephant and an owl)
  - Temperature is set to 220 °C
- **Observations**

  - One of the times that the print failed, I noticed that the temperature had dropped to ~204 °C prior to failing. I don't know if that's normal behavior or not

Comment: Maybe not related, but, what material do you print? A temperature of 220 °C is pretty hot for PLA but on the low side for ABS or PETG.

Comment: @0scar - I believe that I am using PLA. So far, I haven't adjusted any settings - just printed exactly what's in the file I download

Comment: Same problem occurred to me, now twice. How much is the Finder's memory able/allowed to register? After erasing all but the print job, things go smooth.

Comment: Just providing an update: I've gone back and forth with FlashForge support and they're now providing suggestions of parts to replace (in ascending price). If it requires trying everything, I'll likely spend as much as a new machine.

Comment: If the commanded temperature is 220 °C and falls to 204 °C and cannot recover in time, a proper firmware would typically report a ["thermal runaway error"](/q/8466). Are you seeing this?

Answer (score -2):

Try unplugging the USB lead as soon as the printer starts to print (I had similar issue and this worked for me).

Comment: No USB is plugged in during printing